# Change axis intersection and color of lower plot area

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

I am looking for a way to plot a bar chart of two variables in which the beginning of y-axis must be at 100. Also, I need to color every bar that is under the value of 100 as a different color than the others.

Any comments about how can I do this?

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=Year, y=variation, x=Year)) + 
geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity",  fill="yellowgreen")+
theme_minimal(base_size = 15)+
xlab("Year") + ylab ("Variation (%)")+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1995, 2021, 1))
```

Data:

```
 dput(df$Year)

c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2021L, 2021L, 2018L, 2018L, 2004L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2015L, 2015L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2021L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2017L, 2017L, 2021L, 2021L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2011L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2020L, 2018L, 2017L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2011L, 2018L, 2021L, 2014L, 2020L, 2008L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2012L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2015L, 2015L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2011L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2019L, 2016L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2009L, 2009L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2011L, 2020L, 2014L, 2014L, 2007L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2010L, 2010L, 2019L, 2019L, 2013L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 1995L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2005L, 2011L, 2020L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2012L, 2012L, 2016L, 2016L, 2021L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 1997L, 2003L, 2020L, 
2002L, 2019L, 2006L, 2006L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2012L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2014L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
2020L, 2019L, 1996L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2021L, 
2018L, 2017L, 2017L, 2010L, 2010L, 2021L, 2013L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2007L, 2017L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2019L, 2021L, 2021L, 2010L, 
2010L, 2010L, 2014L, 2012L, 2012L, 2018L, 2007L, 2018L, 2020L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2018L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2021L, 2021L, 2018L, 2018L, 2004L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2015L, 2015L, 2021L, 2021L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2021L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2017L, 2017L, 2021L, 2021L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2011L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2020L, 2018L, 
2017L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2020L, 2020L, 2011L, 
2018L, 2021L, 2014L, 2020L, 2008L, 2021L, 2021L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L, 2019L, 2019L, 2012L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2011L, 2009L, 2009L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2019L, 2016L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2009L, 2009L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2011L, 2020L, 2014L, 2014L, 2007L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2010L, 2010L, 2019L, 2019L, 2013L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 1995L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2005L, 2011L, 2020L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2012L, 2012L, 2016L, 2016L, 2021L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 1997L, 2003L, 2020L, 2002L, 2019L, 
2006L, 2006L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2012L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2014L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2020L, 2019L, 
1996L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2021L, 2018L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2010L, 2010L, 2021L, 2013L, 2017L, 2017L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2007L, 2017L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 
2021L, 2021L, 2021L, 2019L, 2021L, 2021L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
2014L, 2012L, 2012L, 2018L, 2007L, 2018L, 2020L, 2009L, 2009L, 
2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2018L)


>   dput(df$variation)
c(170.3703704, 145.035461, 60251.77305, 162.8295484, 177.0086139, 
545.2523364, 517.9754761, 306.2049062, 97.23113287, 134.2267248, 
69.67656362, 87.18901916, 121.8741099, 74.09803434, 1955.555556, 
399.7729484, 1388.058283, 317.3871431, 388.7711864, 640.8898305, 
589.0889831, 466.1016949, 361.0169492, 16.97, 140, 6560, 2704.938272, 
500, 15.79100992, 45.15469936, 194.2307692, 137.3333333, 1550, 
14780, 275, 166.6666667, 120.8333333, 117.8571429, 71.42857143, 
51.78571429, 613.3333333, 161.5384615, 129.3103448, 17739.13043, 
9105.063291, 40186.2069, 201.4705882, 357.1428571, 295.9048027, 
447.733022, 96.78120922, 121.9849836, 40.02713704, 28529.3765, 
3895, 208.8757396, 272.972973, 46.15384615, 51.70575693, 225.0368583, 
95.63953488, 149.6078431, 182.6923077, 36.85279188, 126.7676768, 
140.8036589, 88.07424594, 590, 930, 268.1818182, 422.7272727, 
223.0769231, 292.3076923, 241.6666667, 316.6666667, 285.8921162, 
569.2946058, 150.7658643, 300.2188184, 56.1465721, 162.5, 170.2290076, 
43.90243902, 276.5753425, 301.8867925, 408.3613289, 65.09287926, 
299.3670886, 428.1481481, 541.5730337, 691.3580247, 472.2222222, 
711.7647059, 67.68392371, 103.9509537, 59.59128065, 46.29032258, 
398.2857143, 466.1904762, 1820.083682, 3392.547033, 4166.546763, 
6263.285024, 2892.732139, 195.5684008, 925.9373079, 1216.662401, 
3616.613924, 2696.190102, 1410.658307, 90.90909091, 146.3949843, 
551.7241379, 1032.110092, 66.51376147, 107.1100917, 403.6697248, 
3237.410072, 208.6330935, 335.971223, 1266.18705, 500, 25, 250, 
250, 666.6666667, 33.33333333, 333.3333333, 333.3333333, 200, 
10, 100, 100, 43.5483871, 42.1875, 43.5483871, 42.1875, 211.2745098, 
133.8235294, 375.7142857, 242.8571429, 11824.14809, 111.7647059, 
113.3507853, 75.39267016, 45.28795812, 48.16753927, 37.95811518, 
42.67015707, 146.8899522, 133.3333333, 420.8333333, 820.8333333, 
3066.666667, 979.1666667, 641.6666667, 144.6679317, 25.04743833, 
49.88614801, 134.345351, 169.8056801, 58.89387145, 50.07473842, 
201.1958146, 153.9896373, 112.3670213, 68.51088876, 27.83934267, 
69.60376237, 281.0043786, 188.4642413, 749.7570457, 202.6239067, 
1732.142857, 820.2380952, 78.93852872, 261.8798956, 553.9877301, 
756.9832402, 122.8373702, 140.7407407, 396.2962963, 250.5154639, 
939.1752577, 3097.902098, 1594.405594, 70.93596059, 40.40932889, 
46.66666667, 439.7069597, 178.7545788, 77.28937729, 45.16129032, 
57.14285714, 177.9661017, 131.8681319, 41.81484456, 279.714577, 
32.30769231, 56.13540197, 74.85448196, 261.0983982, 194.7058824, 
256.8, 156.25, 456.0096154, 659.8557692, 1049.278846, 76.92307692, 
253.8461538, 430.6490385, 147.6043277, 109.3692649, 8507.633588, 
538.2008155, 114.8288973, 379.6257796, 293.970894, 264.2766497, 
146.0025381, 125.6339327, 93.31489166, 95.25756337, 43.758967, 
586.7132867, 35.01723523, 146.8468468, 158.0152672, 34.35114504, 
333.3333333, 833.3333333, 433.3333333, 666.6666667, 266.6666667, 
294.1176471, 1076.470588, 488.2352941, 294.1176471, 294.1176471, 
161.0655738, 291.5692554, 274.3684497, 4.255319149, 3.191489362, 
1.861702128, 0.265957447, 0.265957447, 2.659574468, 4.787234043, 
3.723404255, 204.5039164, 189.4345238, 1425.531915, 3051.06383, 
453.9886773, 131.5789474, 281.5699659, 162.7906977, 174.1935484, 
286.2745098, 109.5238095, 65.56286365, 206.7375887, 323.2, 214.9253731, 
97.61388286, 160.4938272, 67.48148148, 72.53164557, 83.36162988, 
159.4580511, 3.751133878, 5.202497199, 201.3636364, 299.0909091, 
992.776541, 200, 1081.818182, 3372.727273, 1338.537344, 752.7251185, 
112.8191489, 544, 188, 780, 585.5987796, 54.29782082, 377.3799127, 
29.47598253, 151.3973799, 173.4061135, 131.1353712, 1697.8389, 
132.6129666, 681.1394892, 780.1571709, 589.9803536, 442.9523321, 
34.59764223, 177.7037417, 203.5366479, 153.9210661, 197.5609756, 
2431.25, 3881.818182, 616.9341317, 4551.435407, 3759.482393, 
300, 331.3555361, 367.3716012, 814.6445131, 320.6690562, 967.4074074, 
56.52173913, 65.70935342, 101.5447154, 24587.5, 14475, 11975, 
19162.5, 201.4606742, 170.3703704, 145.035461, 60251.77305, 162.8295484, 
177.0086139, 545.2523364, 517.9754761, 306.2049062, 97.23113287, 
134.2267248, 69.67656362, 87.18901916, 121.8741099, 74.09803434, 
1955.555556, 399.7729484, 1388.058283, 317.3871431, 388.7711864, 
640.8898305, 589.0889831, 466.1016949, 361.0169492, 16.97, 140, 
6560, 2704.938272, 500, 15.79100992, 45.15469936, 194.2307692, 
137.3333333, 1550, 14780, 275, 166.6666667, 120.8333333, 117.8571429, 
71.42857143, 51.78571429, 613.3333333, 161.5384615, 129.3103448, 
17739.13043, 9105.063291, 40186.2069, 201.4705882, 357.1428571, 
295.9048027, 447.733022, 96.78120922, 121.9849836, 40.02713704, 
28529.3765, 3895, 208.8757396, 272.972973, 46.15384615, 51.70575693, 
225.0368583, 95.63953488, 149.6078431, 182.6923077, 36.85279188, 
126.7676768, 140.8036589, 88.07424594, 590, 930, 268.1818182, 
422.7272727, 223.0769231, 292.3076923, 241.6666667, 316.6666667, 
285.8921162, 569.2946058, 150.7658643, 300.2188184, 56.1465721, 
162.5, 170.2290076, 43.90243902, 276.5753425, 301.8867925, 408.3613289, 
65.09287926, 299.3670886, 428.1481481, 541.5730337, 691.3580247, 
472.2222222, 711.7647059, 67.68392371, 103.9509537, 59.59128065, 
46.29032258, 398.2857143, 466.1904762, 1820.083682, 3392.547033, 
4166.546763, 6263.285024, 2892.732139, 195.5684008, 925.9373079, 
1216.662401, 3616.613924, 2696.190102, 1410.658307, 90.90909091, 
146.3949843, 551.7241379, 1032.110092, 66.51376147, 107.1100917, 
403.6697248, 3237.410072, 208.6330935, 335.971223, 1266.18705, 
500, 25, 250, 250, 666.6666667, 33.33333333, 333.3333333, 333.3333333, 
200, 10, 100, 100, 43.5483871, 42.1875, 43.5483871, 42.1875, 
211.2745098, 133.8235294, 375.7142857, 242.8571429, 11824.14809, 
111.7647059, 113.3507853, 75.39267016, 45.28795812, 48.16753927, 
37.95811518, 42.67015707, 146.8899522, 133.3333333, 420.8333333, 
820.8333333, 3066.666667, 979.1666667, 641.6666667, 144.6679317, 
25.04743833, 49.88614801, 134.345351, 169.8056801, 58.89387145, 
50.07473842, 201.1958146, 153.9896373, 112.3670213, 68.51088876, 
27.83934267, 69.60376237, 281.0043786, 188.4642413, 749.7570457, 
202.6239067, 1732.142857, 820.2380952, 78.93852872, 261.8798956, 
553.9877301, 756.9832402, 122.8373702, 140.7407407, 396.2962963, 
250.5154639, 939.1752577, 3097.902098, 1594.405594, 70.93596059, 
40.40932889, 46.66666667, 439.7069597, 178.7545788, 77.28937729, 
45.16129032, 57.14285714, 177.9661017, 131.8681319, 41.81484456, 
279.714577, 32.30769231, 56.13540197, 74.85448196, 261.0983982, 
194.7058824, 256.8, 156.25, 456.0096154, 659.8557692, 1049.278846, 
76.92307692, 253.8461538, 430.6490385, 147.6043277, 109.3692649, 
8507.633588, 538.2008155, 114.8288973, 379.6257796, 293.970894, 
264.2766497, 146.0025381, 125.6339327, 93.31489166, 95.25756337, 
43.758967, 586.7132867, 35.01723523, 146.8468468, 158.0152672, 
34.35114504, 333.3333333, 833.3333333, 433.3333333, 666.6666667, 
266.6666667, 294.1176471, 1076.470588, 488.2352941, 294.1176471, 
294.1176471, 161.0655738, 291.5692554, 274.3684497, 4.255319149, 
3.191489362, 1.861702128, 0.265957447, 0.265957447, 2.659574468, 
4.787234043, 3.723404255, 204.5039164, 189.4345238, 1425.531915, 
3051.06383, 453.9886773, 131.5789474, 281.5699659, 162.7906977, 
174.1935484, 286.2745098, 109.5238095, 65.56286365, 206.7375887, 
323.2, 214.9253731, 97.61388286, 160.4938272, 67.48148148, 72.53164557, 
83.36162988, 159.4580511, 3.751133878, 5.202497199, 201.3636364, 
299.0909091, 992.776541, 200, 1081.818182, 3372.727273, 1338.537344, 
752.7251185, 112.8191489, 544, 188, 780, 585.5987796, 54.29782082, 
377.3799127, 29.47598253, 151.3973799, 173.4061135, 131.1353712, 
1697.8389, 132.6129666, 681.1394892, 780.1571709, 589.9803536, 
442.9523321, 34.59764223, 177.7037417, 203.5366479, 153.9210661, 
197.5609756, 2431.25, 3881.818182, 616.9341317, 4551.435407, 
3759.482393, 300, 331.3555361, 367.3716012, 814.6445131, 320.6690562, 
967.4074074, 56.52173913, 65.70935342, 101.5447154, 24587.5, 
14475, 11975, 19162.5, 201.4606742)
```

Here's an example of what I'm looking for, but with 100 instead of 0 on the y-axis.

[image]

---

---

Edit:

I edited the axis breaks and limits to make the axis clearer but I'm still not sure if the info I need to be shown is accurately displayed. I have some data that are low as 1%, and these bars should be "hanging" upside down at the x-axis, showing values that are much lower than the 100% parameter at y axis, however, I can only visualize small-sized different colored lines (which I imagine that are these data). I suspect that data lower than 100% are not being proportionally shown. Is there another way to do it?

```
df %>% 
   mutate(var_tr = variation- 100,  fill_color = as.factor(sign(var_tr))) %>% 
   ggplot() + 
   geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=var_tr, fill = fill_color), position="dodge", stat="identity") +
   guides(fill="none") +
   theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
   xlab("Year") + 
   ylab ("Variation (%)") +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100, 62000, 5000), labels = seq(-100, 62000, 5000)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1995, 2021, 1))+
    expand_limits(y = c(-100, 62000),  x = c(1995, 2021))
```

And this is the plot I got:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform your `variation` values by subtracting 100 from them, and then manipulating your axis to show the original values. Here, I made an example dataset. For the actual dataset, instead of hardcoding the `break`, `labels`, and `limits`, you can use `range()`, `min()`, and `max()` functions to have the plot set up.

```r
data.frame(Year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014),
           variation = c(400, 200, 20, 100, 50)) -> df

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  mutate(var_tr = variation - 100, 
         fill_color = as.factor(sign(var_tr))) %>% 
 ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=var_tr, fill = fill_color),
           position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  guides(fill="none") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
  xlab("Year") + 
  ylab ("Variation (%)") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-100, 300, 100),
                     labels = seq(0, 400, 100)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2010, 2014, 1)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(-100, 400), 
                x = c(2010, 2014))
```

[image]

For this specific case, where the data is skewed, we can use transformed scales on the y-axis. See the answer below for the data that OP provided in the question.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggallin)


threshold <- 100

df %>% 
  mutate(var_tr = variation - threshold, 
         fill_color = as.factor(sign(var_tr))) %>% 
 ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=var_tr, fill = fill_color),
           position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  guides(fill="none") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 15) +
  xlab("Year") + 
  ylab ("Variation (%)") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = ggallin::pseudolog10_trans, 
                     breaks = c(-1e2, -10, 0, 10^seq(1,5,1))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1995, 2020, 5)) +
  expand_limits(x = c(1994, 2021))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I adjusted the axis limits to make them fit my entire dataset but I'm getting a weird-looking plot. I'm editing the question to show my output with the code.

Comment: @PatriciaNunes Your data is skewed towards numbers much larger than 100. you can try this to make it cleaner but at the end it will not look like what I have, unless you use a different threshold than 100 like 10,000 or something.

Comment: ```df %>% 
  mutate(var_tr = variation - 100, 
         fill_color = as.factor(sign(var_tr))) %>% 
 ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=var_tr, fill = fill_color),
           position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  guides(fill="none") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
  xlab("Year") + 
  ylab ("Variation (%)") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-100, 0, seq(9900, 59900, 10000)),
                     labels = c(0, 100, seq(10000, 60000, 10000))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1995, 2020, 5)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(-500, 61000), 
                x = c(1990, 2025))```

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to select the beginning of the axis to "zoom in" at the lower interval?

Comment: @PatriciaNunes see the updated answer with logarithmic y-axis scales. That should address your needs.